# Can Apache kafka offer a asynchronous messaging service?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

im about to implement a Chat room using Spring boot and webSocket and also Kafka, but i need to know if Kafka provide an asynchronous messaging service

Comment: It can. Try it out and see if it fits your needs

Comment: how ? ,  i can  use a database that store messages ?

Comment: Kafka stores every message you send to it... Facebook uses an actual database for its chats, though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Apache Kafka provide an asynchronous subscription callback API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546252/does-apache-kafka-provide-an-asynchronous-subscription-callback-api)

Comment: Use MySQL if it is just a toy project. Kafka is not friendly for newbies.

Answer (score 1):

**Apache Kafka is an asynchronous messaging service**.

- **Kafka Producer** is a program which publishes messages to a Kafka Broker.
- **Kafka Broker** is a server which stores messages in a category called Kafka topic.
- **Kafka Consumer** is a program which reads messages from a Kafka topic.

In order to get a hang of how these concepts work try going through the [Kafka Quickstart Tutorial](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart).